# Is it possible to use a different VM image for minikube

Tags: minikube, google-container-os, google-container-optimized-os

I see minikube using Debian rodete as the VM image. I would like to use different image like Container-Optimized OS is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/28/running-kubernetes-locally-on-linux-with-minikube-now-with-kubernetes-1.14-support/#prerequisites) part of the documentation on how to use minikube locally, you can see that ***Any Linux you like*** can be eligible for its use.

Hence, as the Container-Optimized OS (COS) is based on Chromium OS (which is a minimal Linux OS focused on security), per definition, is possible to use the mentioned image.